# Xcode - macro for multiple methods

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods, macros

I would like to put all of the following into one macro so that I can include these methods in different view controllers with one line of code. In this case defining a parent VC with the methods isn't an option.

```
- (void)method1 {
    //do stuff
}

- (void)method2 {
    //do more stuff
}

- (void)method3 {
    //do other stuff
}
```

What/where is the best place to do this? And how?

Comment: Why not put them in a common base class, or in a helper object? While technically macros work, they come with a price tag: essentially duplicated code, hard to debug, etc.

Comment: @Elko I can't use a base class, but can you point me to an example of how to do this in a helper object?

Comment: You can put those methods in another class and instantiate them with the controller object they work on. It won't work easy if they work heavily with private data. You might define an interface for those methods as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare it in a header file that you then import in all of your view controllers. Either use an existing header that fits (AppDelegate maybe) or just create a new one.

```
// ThreeMethods.h
#define ThreeMethods   \
- (void)method1 { \
    //do stuff    \
}                 \
                  \
- (void)method2 { \
    //do more stuff \
}                  \
                     \
- (void)method3 {   \
    //do other stuff \
}                    \
```

```
// ViewController1.m
#import ThreeMethods.h
ThreeMethods
```

```
// ViewController2.m
#import ThreeMethods.h
ThreeMethods
```

You could also import it in your prefix header (the .pch file in your project) that is added to every file before compiling.

Comment: So I have to include the backslash on every line? The methods are fairly large.

Comment: If your methods are large enough that you don't want to spend time putting a backslash on each line, you *really* shouldn't be doing this with a macro.